# How to avoid returning an optional after throwing an exception?

Tags: swift, exception, option-type

I'm writing a utility function which takes a parameter and *always* returns a *valid non-nil* result (notice the returned value is not optional because the possible parameters are all actually hardcoded and valid, so I know the function cannot fail):

```
func myFunction(param: String) -> NonTrivialObject {...}
```

Now, during development I want to experiment with possible parameters and, should I make a mistake, I want the function to throw an exception and just crash. I don't want or need to throw Swift errors or catch them, I want to hard-crash and fix the parameter immediately. In Objective C I would just use `NSParameterAssert()` or do something along these lines:

```
guard let validatedParam = param where param != nil else {
    NSException(...).raise()
    return nil
}
// do the actual work and return a non-optional result
```

However, I cannot return `nil` because the result is not an optional. Is there a way to somehow tell the compiler that it doesn't need to bother returning anything from the function after an exception is thrown? Or am I doomed to litter my code with unwrapping optionals or `try!` statements or to return a dummy object just to make the compiler pleased?

Comment: there is a lot of ways how to crash an application .... are you sure, you like you app to crash? really?swift throwing function is you best friend, believe or not. or you can use guard ..... else { exit(-1) }

Comment: check http://blog.krzyzanowskim.com/2015/03/09/swift-asserts-the-missing-manual/, there is a lot of nice information, which can be very helpful for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Swift `assert(_:_file:line:)` function as follows

```
assert(some condition, "Message to display if condition is false (optional)" )
```

If the condition is verified the app will continue running, otherwise it will terminate

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. Don't even know how I missed assertions, though.

Answer (score 2):

An optional may contain nil, but Swift syntax forces you to safely deal with it using the ? syntax to indicate to the compiler you understand the behavior and will handle it safely.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the function to be a throwing function:

```
func foo(param: String) throws -> NonTrivialObject {
    guard param != nil else {
        throw SomeErrorEnum.NilFound
    }
    doStuff(...)
}
```

The error enum needs to conform to the ErrorType protocol. The function call is now able to catch errors like this:

```
do {
    try foo(param)
} catch SomeErrorEnum.NilFound {
    print("Found nil")
}
```

In this way the function returns a non-optional but can also throw errors. For more information see: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html